# How To Make A counter With Momentjs?

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

Hello every one i'm working on a task that uses moment js so what i want to do is make a counter that count min,sec and hours like the toggl.com counter i have an input field called start and another one called end i want to subtract the finish from start and replace the counter value with it and then the counter continue from the current value for ex the counter is `0:00:10` and `start is: 01:15 PM` and `end is : 01:30 PM` i want to subtract the start from the end which is result the value `00:15` this value replaces the current value of the counter which is `0:00:10` to `0:15:00` then the counter start from this value and add seconds to it as normal counter `0:15:01` and so on please check [toggl.com](https://toggl.com/) to understand what i mean 
2/ i want if i changed the value of start value to any number like `10` and if the time is PM it consider it as `10 PM` not `10 AM`
My  code here can't do that

```
  validate(val:string) {
   let temp =this.startTime;
   let parsedTime = moment(val, "hh:mm A");
   if(parsedTime.isValid()) {
   this.startTime = parsedTime.format('hh:mm A')
   } else {
    this.startTime = "temp";
    console.log("no"); 
   }
  }
```

where the `val` the enterd value in the start input field also i want if i entered an unexpected format it replaces it with the previous valid time not `temp` string i tried `this.startTime = this.StartTime` but it doesn't work i want the validation looks like toggl.com please visit it 
[image]

and this is my counter code with my own work for some i don't expect this is the wanted one for this behaviour

```
  startPause() {// when click on play button
this.bs = moment();
this.startTime = this.bs.format('hh:mm A');
this.play = false;
this.pause = true;

let sec= 0;
let min = 0;
let hour = 0;
 this.countup = setInterval(() => {
  if(sec === 59) {
    min++;
    sec = 0;
  }else if(min > 59) {
    hour++;
    min = 0;
  }else {
    sec++;
  }
  this.timer = `${this.pad(hour)}:${this.pad(min)}:${this.pad(sec)}`;
}, 1000);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
App.directive("timerup", function(Util,$interval,$timeout){
  return {
    scope: { start: '=' },
    require: "?ngModel",
    //template: "<input type='text' readonly class='form-control' ng-model='value' > ",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){

        if (!ngModel) return;

        ngModel.$render = function(){
            scope.value = ngModel.$modelValue;
        };

        var timeout = 0;
        $interval(function () {
            if((scope.start)){
                //factory('Util', [function () {
                return element.text(Util.dhms(Math.floor((new Date().getTime() - scope.start.getTime())/ 1000)));
            }
        }, 1000);

        function onTimeout() {
            //timeout = timeout +1;
            timeout++;
        }
    }
  };
});
App.factory('Util', [function () {
    return {
        dhms: function (t) {
            var days, hours, minutes, seconds;
            days = Math.floor(t / 86400);
            t -= days * 86400;
            hours = Math.floor(t / 3600) % 24;
            t -= hours * 3600;
            minutes = Math.floor(t / 60) % 60;
            t -= minutes * 60;
            seconds = t % 60;
            return [
                (days)? days + 'd': '',
                (hours)? hours + 'h':'',
                minutes + 'm',
                seconds + 's'
            ].join(' ');
        }
    };
}]);

<span timerup ng-model="model" start="start"</span>
```

start = Initial Date